# JS built in number sum function

Tags: javascript

Does JS have a number sum method? i.e., Math.sum(num1,num2) or something?

The reason is that I have 2 arrays of like 10 elements each, and I want to combine them into a single array by applying a custom function on each pair of elements (such as addition or multiplication). Would be much cleaner to have something like Math.sum instead of my own function

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
//custom function for each pair of numbers
var operations = [Math.sum, Math.multiply, Math.sum];
//apply the functions to get [5,10,9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use functional programming.
Reduce method of arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    \\code...

    return accumulator
}, [])
```

Last `[]` means source, where you want to collect the new result.
You always must return accumulator.

Here you have more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

You can check out math.js, it has a [sum](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/sum.html) function.

Arrow functions are much cleaner than traditional functions. You can store them in an array or object:

```
var utils = { sum: (n1, n2) => n1 + n2, product: (n1, n2) => n1 * n2 };
var operations = [ utils.sum, utils.product, utils.sum ];
```